# jQuery: Cannot access text box value using .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a dynamic table that users can add to, delete from, or edit. I have the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_rule', function() {
    // editable text boxes for name and description
    $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(3)").each(function() {
        var html = $(this).html();
        var input = $('<input type="text" />');
        input.val(html);
        $(this).html(input);
    });

    // replace Edit and Delete with Save and Cancel
    $(".edit_rule").replaceWith("<input id='Button' type='button' value='Save' class='sav$
    $(".delete_rule").replaceWith("<input id='Button' type='button' value='Cancel' class=$

});
```

Which all works fine. But, when I try to access the new values in the next boxes, the value comes up blank.  I was trying to use .val() and now am trying .text() as follows:

```
$(document).on('click', '.save_edit', function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var $name = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)").find('input');
    console.log($name.text()); // prints empty string
});
```

I'm fairly new to Javascript, so is there some weird scope thing I'm not understanding that prevents the value from being accessed in a separate function? Is there another way to do it?

EDIT: Here is the corresponding HTML

```
<div id="customperms_table_container" style="height:655px;">
    <table id="customperms_table_form" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="$
        <caption></caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Role Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add html mark up as well

Comment: change from `$name.text()` to `$name.val()`, since that is already an input field

Comment: Broken HTML, update with right one.

Comment: Please post runnable code snippet

Answer (score 0):

1. Issue is `td` has no value.
2. Solution is use `.text()` or `.html()` to get its text or html

Based on comment:

Your selector should be:

```
var $name = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)").find('input')// add class or id if there other inputs
```

Comment: .text() comes up blank and .html() comes back as '<input type="text">'

Comment: thought that would be it, but both html and text return blank strings. it's almost as if the value typed into the text box just doesn't exist to the javascript after the page is loaded

Comment: @Mike did you change the selector by adding find input? should work

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about broken html, but combo of guradio and Haze fixed it.

```
var $name = $row.find("td:nth-child(3)");
console.log($name.val()); // <-- prints correct value
```